# JSP Bean class atribute is invalid

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, jsp, tomcat

Имеется такой класс:

```
package jsp;

public class Person
{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Person()
  {}

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

и имеется такой JSP файл:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:useBean id="person" scope="request" class="jsp.Person" type="jsp.Person"
    beanName="jsp.Person"/>
    <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="name" value="Test"/>
    <jsp:getProperty name="person" property="name"/>
</body>
</html>
```

при запуске сервера и перехода на данную JSP страницу получается ошибка:

> The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid

используется Tomcat версии 9.0.7

Бьюсь над этим уже пару дней. Облазил и забугорный stackoverflow и русский. Ни создание конструктора по умолчанию, ничего другого не помогло. Надеюсь, вы сможете помочь мне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файл `Person.class` должен находиться в папке `/WEB-INF/classes/jsp`.

---

Для создания бина

```
<jsp:useBean id="person" class="jsp.Person" scope="request" />
```

Comment: к сожалению, такой вариант тоже не работает

Comment: ак как вам такой вариант?

Comment: К сожалению, тоже. Не хочет запускаться. При обновлении страницы эксепшен меняется. с ClassNotFoundException org.apache.jsp.jsp.beans_jsp до attribute is invalid

Comment: теперь такой вариант должен работать